# What is a proper way of testing a method using Mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am currently trying to test a method using Mockito and I am stuck on a certain method.

For example, there are classes called Car and CarSystem.

The car class contains two parameters, Name(String) and its License Plate(String) and their getter/setter methods.

The method I am trying to test using Mockito is a method called, addCar which is in the CarSystem class.

CarSystem class:

```
private final List<Car> cars= new ArrayList<>();

public Car addCar(String name, String plateNumber) throws IllegalStateException {
        Car clash = getCar(plateNumber);
        if (null != clash) throw new IllegalStateException("Car with that Number already exists");

        Car car = new Car(name, plateNumber);
        cars.add(car);

        return car;
    }


public Car getCar(String match) {
        for (Car car: cars) {
            if (car.getPlateNumber().equals(match)) return car;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

What I am trying to test is the two things:

1. It successfully throws an IllegalStateException exception when there is a car with the plate number that already exists in the car list.
2. It successfully adds a car to the list.

What I did solely using JUnit is:

```
@Test
    public void testAddCar_ThrowingException() {

        try {

            CarSystem sys = new CarSystem();
            Car car = sys.addCar("1234", "Toyota123");
            Car car1= sys.addCar("1234", "Honda123");
            Assert.fail();
        } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

@Test
    public void testAddCar() {

            CarSystem sys = new CarSystem();
            Car car = sys.addCar("1234", "Toyota123");
            Assert.assertEquals(sys.getCar(1234).getName(), "Toyota123");
    }
```

But I have no idea how to test them using Mockito... Can anyone please help me or give me a hint about this?

P.S) I can freely change the content of the classes for Mockito test.

Comment: Your test looks perfectly fine. I don't understand why you would want to use Mockito for this. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: You dont use mocking frameworks because you *can*. You use them when you **need** them. And: if you can fully test your code *without* using a mocking framework, then you always prefer that! Mocking frameworks add another dependency, and complexity to your code base. If you want to understand WHY you have to use them sometimes, dont start with your current code. Pick up a good tutorial on Mockito, and read how it is SUPPOSED to work.

Comment: BTW, your first test can be cleaned up with `@Test(expected=IllegalStateException.class)`. Then you don't need the manual `Assert.fail()`, or the try-catch.

Comment: Why are you returning `null` in both `getCar()` and `addCar()`?

Comment: I just want to test them independently. The test suite I wrote is for the CarSystem class, and what I am trying is to isolate the test, not making it dependent on Car class.

Comment: @GhostCat I disagree, you should mock whenever possible, rather than creating a proper object; it is more resilient to changes down the line (eg changes in the constructor for which you'd unecessarily need to adjust the test if you only need one field you can mock a getter for). As for the dependency, you'd have that if you use Mockito even once in any of your test classes.

Comment: @daniu So, how should I apply mockito to the exisiting tests? I can change the code for the classes to make them testable tho...

Comment: @daniu One point of doing TDD and unit tests is to get yourself to write *testable* code. If your production code makes it **so hard** to create objects of a certain class that you prefer a mocking framework ... then you are just working around a symptom. Because that means that already writing "functional tests" is hard, too. 
Sure, there is a bit of grey area, but I think the better strategy is the one I outlined. Mocking is the last resort, not the first option. And when your "constructors" change so often that it becomes a problem, then that by itself is a problem.

Comment: @GhostCat Actually, I consier TDD a perfect example why you should prefer Mockito since it allows to test against methods of interfaces that are not implemented yet. I agree with you on the testable code, and to some extent with how hard it is to create objects in my current environment (which is driven the desire for immutable data objects implemented with an all args constructor and no setters :/). But did prefer mocking before because it better abstracts from an eventual implementation. It's just a clean why to make the assumption "if X does this, I expect...".

Comment: @seung Why is the car system creating the car object? That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @daniu It is just a name, the class name can be anything. I just created the name... I just want to know how to apply mockito to that existing test code... (addCar actually returns the car, not Null, and I can freely change the existing codes to make the codes testable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not create the `Car` to be added inside the method but have it passed in as a parameter, ie

```
interface CarService {
  Car addCar(Car toAdd);
  Car getCar(String plateNumber);
}
```

Since you are testing the service itself, you cannot mock it - only the car. Since the `Car`'s only data you access is `getPlateNumber`, a test would look something like this:

```
class ScratchTest {
    private CarService sut;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        sut = new CarService();
    }

    @Test
    public void addSucceeds() {
        String plateNumber = "new";
        Car toAdd = mock(Car.class);
        when(toAdd.getPlateNumber()).thenReturn(plateNumber);
        Car added = sut.addCar(toAdd);

        // assert return value
        assertSame(toAdd, added);
        // assert car now available via get
        Car stored = sut.getCar(plateNumber);
        assertSame(toAdd, stored);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void addFails() {
        Car existing = mock(Car.class);
        String plateNumber = "existing";
        when(existing.getPlateNumber()).thenReturn(plateNumber);
        sut.addCar(existing);
        Car toAdd = mock(Car.class);
        when(toAdd.getPlateNumber()).thenReturn(plateNumber);

        sut.addCar(toAdd);
    }
}
```

You cannot really test add and get independently, because they are invariants of each other: 1. If `add` is called with a car with a new plate number, a subsequent `get` given that plate number will retrieve it, and 2. If `get` is called with the plate number of a `Car` for which `add` has been called before, it will be returned.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniu!! BTW should I add verify() test within  public void addSucceeds()? or should I test for verification seperately? Also, is there anyway that I can use dependency injection for making the code more testable?

Comment: @seung You could use `verify` but I don't see the point; you could inject the list, but that's really a different question. If you were to do so, it would make more sense to use `verify` (on the injected list to make sure that `add` has been called).

Comment: What do you mean by injecting the list? Could you please give me more details?